# Using the string formatting operator to dynamically name global variables

Tags: python

I am trying to create a variable for each element in the list. I want to supply only the element itself as a basis for a new name, yet Python doesn't let me create it that way nor throws any error. It creates the variables when I include any character before the `%` sign. Please see the code below:

```
sample_tickers
```

Out: `['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'JPM']`

Works:

```
for ticker in sample_tickers:

    globals()["var%s"%ticker] = ticker
```

Doesn't work:

```
for ticker in sample_tickers:
    globals()["%s"%ticker] = ticker
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using a dictionary instead?

Comment: It works for me. You probably didn't paste the code you ran. Anyway what do you mean by "*python doesn't let me create it*", and how did you test that?

Comment: I want to create a variable for each ticker, so I can later assign a quandl time series to each of those tickers. I don't know if I can use dictionary for that purpose. By "python doesn't let me create it" I mean that I run the code, there is no error, but the variables are not created. I have python 2.7 if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
sample_tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'JPM']

for ticker in sample_tickers:
    globals()[ticker] = ticker
```

However, creating a dictionary instead of dynamically naming variables is recommended:

```
ticker_dict = dict(zip(sample_tickers,sample_tickers))
# {'AAPL': 'AAPL', 'MSFT': 'MSFT', 'AMZN': 'AMZN', 'FB': 'FB', 'JPM': 'JPM'}
```

Which you can then access like this:

```
ticker_dict['AAPL'] # returns 'AAPL'
```

Comment: The dictionary aproach works as intended, but when I execute your first solution my python 2.7 doesn't create the variables.

This works, but I would like solely the ticker as a name:
globals()['foo'+ticker] = ticker

Comment: It works for me in Python 2.7. How are you testing whether the variable was created?

Comment: A dictionary is suitable for what you're trying to achieve. You can assign a new value (for example a list) to an entry like this `ticker_dict['AAPL'] = [1,2,3]`

Comment: I executed the code in Spyder. The variables from `globals()[ticker] = ticker` were not shown in the variable explorer for some reason, but the ones from `globals()['foo'+ticker] = ticker` were shown properly. So both of your aproaches indeed work, thank you for the help.